# select records in table

Tags: sql-server-2008

We have a table with following fields

```
name    nvarchar(10) 
family  nvarchar(20)
```

The table contains the following  Record

```
jach stonre

sara sufia

mona morgan
```

The following code is written to select

```
select * from tblUser as ta
where ta.Name in('%j%')
```

Why does the output code ?

Comment: I don't get it. What do you mean by "Why does the output code?"

Comment: jackStonre
: please consider accepting an answer if it solved your problem.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want:

```
select * from tblUser as ta
where ta.Name LIKE N'%j%'
```

Comment: How the two characters  ?                 select * from tblUser as ta
where ta.Name LIKE N'%j%' ,  LIKE N'%ة%'

Comment: Mitch is absolutely right. You have to specify the N prefix whenever dealing with the Unicode character (nvarchar/nchar).

Comment: @Mitch: can you provide some more explanation regarding performance implications whenever using the N prefix for nvarchar/nchar????

Comment: @Yogesh Bhadauirya: I think I was incorrect: it's only the other way around: if you use a nvarchar literal together with an indexed varchar column, the varchar column will be converted to nvarchar, and that precludes use of the index. (Because the index is sorted on an 8-bit value, not a 16-bit value.) Thus, you would get the right result, but performance could be reduced (or even poor).